# Cocos2D 2.0 templates for iOS crashing on Mac Pro, but not MacBook pro

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Please help!

I just downloaded Cocos2D 2.0 for iPhone and installed the templates into Xcode 4.5 running on a Mac Pro (ATI Radeon HD 5770) with 10.8.2. I created a project from the template, built and ran it. The splashscreen displays on the simulator, then the app dies with a SIGABRT inside CCES2Renderer.m in initWithDepthFormat on the line:

```
if( ! sharegroup )
    context_ = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
```

Any project I try with Cocos2D, including the test cocos2d-ios project does the same thing on my Mac Pro...BUT...works perfectly on my MacBook Pro.

Does anyone have ANY ideas what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: I would really suggest you take this discussion over to the coco2d forums: ... Wait, you already posted a thread there. Make sure you label it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I've searched everywhere for anything close to this behavior and can't find anything. So strange. Everything else works on my Mac Pro...as a matter of fact, it's my main development machine. Crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the iOS Simulator in Xcode 4.5.

I downloaded Xcode 4.5.1 and it no longer crashes.